# JavaScript: I am trying to use a setInterval() function to generate one message every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript

Currently I am running a setInterval() funnction to populate a div with new messages and I am attempting it to populate one at a time, however my current setInterval() is generating multiple at a time. How can I fix this?

Here's my code snippet:

```
function newMessage(){
            // Loop goes through emails and creats divs for subject, date, sender, and body
         for(var i = 0; i < window.geemails.length; i++ ) {

            //email container
            var div = document.createElement("div");

            //date
            var dateField = document.createElement("h1");
            dateField.className = "date";
            dateField.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].date;
            div.appendChild(dateField);

            //subject
            var subjectField = document.createElement("h1");
            subjectField.className = "subject";
            subjectField.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].subject;
            div.appendChild(subjectField);

            //sender
            var senderField = document.createElement("h1");
            senderField.className = "sender";
            senderField.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].sender;
            div.appendChild(senderField);

            //body
            var bodyField = document.createElement("p");
            bodyField.className = "body";
            bodyField.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].body;
            div.appendChild(bodyField);

            //Separate message content into containers
            document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);

            //inbox counter
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "You have " + window.geemails.length + " messages";


         }

    }


        newMessage();



        //interval for loading new messages
        function addNewMessage() {
            setInterval(function(){window.geemails.push(getNewMessage());newMessage();}, 3000);
        }

        addNewMessage();
```

Comment: Look at my answer, you're calling addNewMessage in your interval function, which will fire it multiple times (surprised it didn't crash your browser)

Answer (score 0):

```
//interval for loading new messages
function addNewMessage() {
    setInterval(function () {
        window.geemails.push(getNewMessage());
        newMessage();
    }, 3000);
}
```

setTimeout will only happen once. setInterval will occur every x milliseconds.

**UPDATE** the problem with your code is you were calling addNewMessage inside your interval function. You don't need to do that when you call setInterval.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like that function is outside of it. When I removed it, the setInterval stopped working. I am thinking the problem has to do with the function newMessage(), at the top of the code. I think it is just creating another set of messages (which is 10) when I really want it to just create 1 new message every 3 seconds.

Comment: No you had addNewMessage invoked INSIDE your addNewMessage function, which I removed in my example. You call addNewMessage outside of the fucntion no reason it wont fire.